# Python NumPy Array Data Type

Tags: python, string, numpy

```
import numpy as np  

d=np.dtype([('name',np.str_),('salary',np.int64)])  
arr = np.array([('Vedant',80000),('Subodh',4000)],dtype=d)  
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[('', 80000) ('',  4000)]
```

Why are the strings blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set how many chars you want to insert. `('name',np.str_, 4)` this expect each word has only four chars. Or use `('name','U10')` for considering **ten chars**, `('name','U18')` for considering **18 chars** without specifying.

```
import numpy as np  

d=np.dtype([('name',np.str_, 4),('salary',np.int64)])  

# we can define dtype like below without specifying the length of words
# BUT we should pay attention 'U10' only considers ten chars
# OR 'U18' for considering 18 chars
# d=np.dtype([('name','U10'),('salary',np.int64)])  

arr = np.array([('abcde',80000),('Subodh',4000)],dtype=d)  
print(arr)  
# [('abcd', 80000) ('Subo',  4000)]
# skip 'e' from 'abcde'
# skip 'dh' from 'Subodh'
```

Comment: I would use the `('name', 'U10')` style.  The shape for the float is an unnecessary complication here.